# What is the procedure for removing "powerful/energetic" materials from home?

Tags: mantras, prayer, idols, prayaschitta, yantra

If someone brought powerful materials like sri chakra, yantras, and salagramas and kept them in their home. Then they should pray to them with special procedures. If they don't offer special worship and follow special rules then it will lead to unexpected and negative consequences.

So, if one brought it with ignorance and hence wants to remove them from home, then what is the procedure to do so?

Materials asked here refer to be both metallic and paper.

Comment: One needs to do Visarjan or donate them to Temples .. Better to consult a Guruji or priest and do as they say.